# PHP CodeSniffer WordPress via Composer

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, phpcodesniffer

Is there a way to install [PHPCodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) and [WordPress Coding Standards for PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards) per project via [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/)?
I've installed both as dev dependencies and set the installed path to WordPress Coding Standards in CodeSniffer.conf.
Unfortunately phpcs can not resolve to the config file when I run the command in the terminal because it is looking in "vendor" folder for "vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.conf"

Here is my project setup:

composer.json

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.2",
        "wp-coding-standards/wpcs": "^0.14.0"
    }
}
```

CodeSniffer.conf

```
<?php
    $phpCodeSnifferConfig = array (
        'installed_paths' => 'vendor/wp-coding-standards/wpcs',
    )
?>
```

Terminal

```
vendor/bin/phpcs -p THEME_NAME --standard=WordPress
```

"ERROR: the "WordPress" coding standard is not installed. The installed coding standards are PEAR, Zend, PSR2, MySource, Squiz and PSR1"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, you don't need to require PHP CodeSniffer explicitly, because `wp-coding-standards/wpcs` pulls it automatically.

`composer.json`

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "wp-coding-standards/wpcs": "^0.14.0"
    }
}
```

is sufficient.

To make CodeSniffer aware of the added coding standard, type on the console terminal:

```
$ vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths vendor/wp-coding-standards/wpcs
```

It will automatically create (and later find) the `vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.conf` file.

> This should have happened automagically during the installation; the package contains instructions for that, but for some reason they were not executed.

Now, check the installed standards:

```
$ vendor/bin/phpcs -i
The installed coding standards are MySource, PSR2, Squiz, Zend, PSR1, PEAR, WordPress-Extra, WordPress, WordPress-Core, WordPress-VIP and WordPress-Docs
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed.
Just a follow up question.
I also came to a similar point but I wanted to add move the `CodeSniffer.conf` file to root level to track it via git and not have it stored in vendors, which you typically exclude.
Is there a way to point phpcs to another path where to look for the config?

Comment: The `CodeSniffer.conf` is an internal file. Add your custom configuration to your own `ruleset.xml` - https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Annotated-ruleset.xml

Comment: To automate the registration of the code standards on `composer install` and `composer update`, use the https://github.com/Dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer Composer plugin (which WPCS recommends).